# C# convert hex string to uint array

Tags: c#

I have a body of text that is innertext inside of an XML. Here are 3 lines of that string for example

```
0x2007A3C8,0xAE8900B8,
0x2007A3CC,0x000E5320,
0x2007A3D0,0x03E00008
```

So the innertext property is a string. I am trying to convert this entire string back into an uint array. So that for every comma adds a new array element.

```
x , x
x , x
```

Would be a total of 4 array elements.

I want to keep the hex syntax, everything. I just need this back into an uint array. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to [split the string](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/split-string-in-C-Sharp/), then [parse it to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715534/long-parse-c-sharp), [convert the long value to string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0), and finally [join the strings back again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0).

Comment: How do you go from 6 input numbers to 4 output numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems to be [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be homework and shows no own commitment so far.

Comment: Your provided data seems inconsistent to me `3 lines` `6 values` `4 array elements`. How do you go from `3 lines` or `6 values` to `4 array elements`? To me it is also unclear if you want to have one array with all the values or seperate arrays for each line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse hex values into a uint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98559/how-to-parse-hex-values-into-a-uint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
string input = "0x2007A3C8,0xAE8900B8, 0x2007A3CC,0x000E5320, 0x2007A3D0,0x03E00008";
string[] strNumbers = input.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
uint[] numbers =  Array.ConvertAll(strNumbers, z => Convert.ToUInt32(z.Trim(), 16));
```

Comment: this works. but its giving me the actual int value of the hex values. ex "537371648" how can i get those back to the 0x20000 hex values that are an array?

Comment: @bismofunyuns - If you want the hex values, then just omit the last line and you'll have a `string[]` array of hexadecimal values. Since a hexadecimal number contains letters and numbers, the data type must be a *string* and not a *uint* type.

Comment: Are you sure? When I declare an uint array, as long as I have the 0x before the 8 digit hex, it doesn’t throw any errors and works normally. 

I need to pass these array values through a function that I am writing to memory with

Comment: m = new MemorySharp(Process.GetProcessesByName(PCSX2PROCESS).FirstOrDefault());
            uint address = 0;
            uint data = 1;
            uint Length = (uint)ASM.Length;
            while (address < Length)
            {
                m.Write((IntPtr)ASM[address], ASM[data], false);
                address += 2;
                data += 2;
            }

Comment: the params of m.write are uint and intptr. i'm trying to remove the asm code completely from my program into an xml file that needs to be decrypted , i've got that part done but now i need to get this encrypted string back into uint format while keeping the hex format.

Comment: actually i was wrong. apparently those hex format gets put into int when i set a breakpoint on the m.write .. your method is perf. thx a lot m8!

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely propose using LINQ for that:

```
var initialString = "0x2007A3C8,0xAE8900B8,\n0x2007A3CC,0x000E5320,\n0x2007A3D0,0x03E00008";
var unsignedValues = initialString
                            .Split(',')
                            .Select(n => Convert.ToUInt32(n.Trim(), 16));
```

Don't really understand about "keeping the hex syntax", but you can sustain it like this, I guess:

```
var initialString = "0x2007A3C8,0xAE8900B8,\n0x2007A3CC,0x000E5320,\n0x2007A3D0,0x03E00008";
var unsignedValues = initialString
                            .Split(',')
                            .Select(n => "0x" + Convert.ToUInt32(n.Trim(),16));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).